# No space free and login loop as user

Tags: debian, xorg, sudo, login-screen

I have had the issue, that I couldn't start a programme. I have read that the following command would fix it:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/
```

and

```
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
```

Trying these commands did not resolve the issue. I now have lost all my free space got lost (0 bytes free) and cannot log-in with my user account (after typing the password screen gets black for less then a second and I end up on the log-ins screen).

However, I can log in with the root account.

Furthermore:

```
root@debian:~# ls -ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 94208 Jul 14 14:59 /usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 May 31 23:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/
```

**Update:** Googling 'debian bounce back to login screen' brought the clue, that something with the X-related scripts might be wrong.

Now: how can I undo / fix this issue (or these issues)? It might be unrelated to the operations done, however all my free space is gone, even after deleting some files.

Comment: Add output of `ls -ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/` to your question.

Comment: Your `ln` command only creates in `/usr/bin` a symbolic link from `platforms` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/`.

Comment: So, do you think the issue of having 0 bytes free and being unable to log-in comes from another source?

Comment: If you used `ln` exactly as described, then the cause is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks!

Going through my .bash_history, I have used the ```ldd /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so``` command, yet there is no folder such as ```./qt/.```. Does that maybe give a hint?

Comment: To be on the safe side, I would not reboot your system until the cause of the hard disk usage has been found. You can start search with `cd /; du -csh *`.

Comment: I have done that, I can't see any anomaly. I've updated the problem description, I think the whole issue could be x-related. The programme I wanted to use gave an error message related to xcb.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by freeing space (neither regular delete, nor deleting as root helped) using the following line:

`sudo apt-get -y autoremove && sudo apt-get -y clean`

Answer (score 0):

The command `df` is made for this. It shows you how much room is free in the different partitions. From the fact that your users are not able to log-in, I would suggest to look especially at the partitions where `/home`, `/tmp` and `/var/log` reside.

If it is in `/var/log` that is over 100%, delete some old log files that you probably wont't use. You need just a little bit of room and you can save the rest of the logfiles later. If it is `/tmp`, look for the largest files. For `/home`, use your own judgement.

Your comment indicated that both `/var` (and `/var/log`) and `/tmp` are on your root partition. And your root partition is full. ANY command that frees up some space in `/var` or `/tmp` would give you some breathing space. Your `apt-get -y autoremove && sudo apt-get -y clean` removes some files from `/var`, which gives you the required space.

However: you should investigate why your root partition is suddenly full.

Comment: ```df``` gives the following output:
`Filesystem     ...    Use% Mounted on
udev          ...      4016408   0% /dev
tmpfs            ...       796032   2% /run
/dev/sda5    ...  100% /
tmpfs            ...   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs            ...     0% /run/lock
tmpfs            4027692         0   4027692   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2     ...  21% /boot/efi
tmpfs            ...  1% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb1      976519104 630453664 346065440  65% /media/root/externalHD
tmpfs             805536         4    805532   1% /run/user/112 `

Comment: TL;DR: /dev/sda5 has 100%, my external HD has 65 %, the rest is clearly below.